# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'RandomNumberGenerator._generator_ctor' on <module 'gym.utils.seeding'

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I was using Open AI gym to train an RL model to play Mario but this is the error I'm getting and I can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: How is anyone expected to offer any assistance here with just an error message and literally nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to upgrade gym to version 0.25.1 by running
`pip install gym --upgrade`