# Attribute Error: 'RandomNumberGenerator._generator_ctor' in gym.utils.seeding

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, rllib

I´m trying to run a reinforcement learning algorithm for a production line optimization. As an engineering student I am not very familiar with coding so I´m looking for help from you guys.

I get this error when trying to train the agent: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'RandomNumberGenerator._generator_ctor' on <module 'gym.utils.seeding'

I´m curious because it doesn´t seem to be related to my code but gym (Can be totally wrong though).
Any ideas? If you need further information about the problem please tell me. Idk whats necessary to know.
I use Python 3.9 on VS on Windows 10 if that helps

Thx for any help :)

I was running the agents training. It started the local ray instance for the training but then the forementioned error popped up

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, you should try to use gym version 0.25.2 or below (just use `pip install gym==0.25.2`) because some modules might be deprecated such as mentioned in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73710249/openai-gym-retro-error-attributeerror-module-gym-utils-seeding-has-no-attri).

Or, you can use version 0.25.1, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73135852/attributeerror-cant-get-attribute-randomnumbergenerator-generator-ctor-on).